# How to get only file not with all path of directory with findfiles in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want get only file not file with all directory path by using groovy findfiles

my code looks just like this:

```
 def dateien = findFiles(glob: "**/xx/xx/xx/*.zip")

 dateien.each {
                echo "upload file ${it.name} to ${trgDir}"

                upload(serverId, "${it.name}", "${trgDir}${it.name}")
        
    }
```

in documentation I see you can it.name to get only file, by it was not workling.

so, maybe you have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think the `name` attribute is not working? as that is the correct approach. Are you sure the  `findFiles` returned something?

Comment: I have run my code, but I can not see anything

Comment: There is no way to answer this without knowing what type of object `dateien` is and if it is a collection, what type of elements are in the collection.

Comment: Is `findFiles` a function of your own, or are you invoking this from a Jenkins step?

Comment: @user1938143 is the path in which you are searching for within your workspace? as this step can we used only for finding files in the current working directory.